# Varying ranges in sum and criteria range for IF statments

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, range

Hey guys I need help with my novice skills at VBA code writing. I would like to modify the code below to accommodate the varying ranges of data rows for my sum range and criteria range in a SUMIF statment.

```
Sub sumifstate ()

Set critRange = Range("K2", Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0)).Select
Set sumRange = Range("L2", Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0)).Select
Set critRange2 = Range("M2", Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0)).Select
Set sumRange2 = Range("N2", Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0)).Select

Range("K41").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=     (SUMIF("critRange",""*DF*"","sumRange")+SUMIF("critRange2,""*DF*"","sumRange2")"

End Sub ()
```

I hope I was specific enough if not let me know what other information you might need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no guarantee that all four of those columns have data in the same last row. However, each `SUMIF` *requires* that all ranges have the same size. Use the same formula for each of the pairs. You are also not evaluating hte formula within VBA, merely constructing a string together. You can use the ranges' addresses as strings for this.

```
Sub sumifstate()
    Dim lr As Long, critRange As String, sumRange As String, critRange2 As String, sumRange2 As String

    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
    critRange = Range("K2:K" & lr).Address
    sumRange = Range("L2:L" & lr).Address
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
    critRange2 = Range("M2:M" & lr).Address
    sumRange2 = Range("N2:N" & lr).Address

    Range("K41").Formula = _
        "=SUMIF(" & critRange & ", ""*DF*"", " & sumRange & ")+SUMIF(" & critRange2 & ", ""*DF*"", " & sumRange2 & ")"

End Sub
```

The formula produced will be dynamic but in this format.

```
=SUMIF($K$2:$K$10, "*DF*", $L$2:$L$10)+SUMIF($M$2:$M$10, "*DF*", $N$2:$N$10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi,

So where you've got R[-39] or R[-3], you want to insert a variable for your actual calculated rows?

```
intStartRow = GetStartRow() ' i.e. however you define it, set a variable
intEndRow = GetEndRow()
```

Then replace where needed:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=(SUMIF(R[" & intStartRow & "]C:R[" & intEndRow & "]C, ...
```

i.e. use concatenate symbol "&",

Either that or use "=Offset" formula combined with Counta: that allows you to have "growing/shrinking" ranges without having to rerun your code